# How to change DataFrame Series from price to percentage with pandas/python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataFrame with date,time and stock price like this:

```
+------------+-------+-------+-------+
|            | 08:01 | 08:02 | 08:03 |
+------------+-------+-------+-------+
| 01/01/2016 | 50    | 50.5  | 50.7  |
+------------+-------+-------+-------+
| 02/01/2016 | 49.6  | 49.5  | 49.6  |
+------------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Now I would like to change the prices to price changes on the day. The first price would always be 0%. It should look something like this:

```
+------------+-------+--------+-------+
|            | 08:01 | 08:02  | 08:03 |
+------------+-------+--------+-------+
| 01/01/2016 | 0     | 0.01   | 0.014 |
+------------+-------+--------+-------+
| 02/01/2016 | 0     | -0.002 | 0     |
+------------+-------+--------+-------+
```

The formula is: `(stockPrice/stockOpenPrice)-1`

How can I code this transformation?

Comment: Maybe `pandas.DataFrame.apply(func, axis=0, broadcast=False, raw=False, reduce=None, args=(), **kwds)` (which applies a function along an input axis of DataFrame) or - if elementwise attack needed -  `pandas.DataFrame.applymap(func)` with a lambda could be used? Did you try this route already or did you try another way to tackle this. Would be good to know for us wanting to support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use difference by [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) with first column selected by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and last substract `1`:

```
print (df.div(df.iloc[:, 0], axis=0) - 1)
            08:01     08:02  08:03
01/01/2016    0.0  0.010000  0.014
02/01/2016    0.0 -0.002016  0.000
```